# FIFA 12 online Custom formation in Head to Head Seasons?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 online can we use custom formation in Head to Head Seasons mode ? In Team Management I couldn't edit the formations but then I still saw someone with weird formation which is probably not in standard formation list.

Comment: +1 I have been wondering the same. Are you on PC or console?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake, I am on PC. Finally, I have found the trick. We can create custom formations and custom tactics in exhibition match then use them in Head to Head Seasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the trick. We can create custom formations and custom tactics in exhibition match then use them in Head to Head Seasons.

Comment: Can you tell me _where_ exactly you can do this? Screenshot would be nice.

Comment: You can do it in Kick Off match or in Customize FIFA -> Edit teams -> Formations -> Press X. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust positions of players before the game, slide them up or down. Probably what noticed. You can do this during timeframe where other options are formation, squad etc.

Answer (score 0):

EA currently do not allow this. This is possibly because as the teams update in real life, you will have to manually change the formation all the time. whatever the reason is, it is not possible at this moment in time. Regarding your player that you saw, he possibly hacked but I am unsure.

Comment: I am sure that is not the formation in real life cause I played the same team as him and my default formation is different.